# Rearranging PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 queries that produce these 2 arrays

```
[{"FGNo":"5"},{"FGNo":"3"},{"FGNo":"4"},{"FGNo":"6"}]
```

and

```
[{"FGNo":"3","Actual":"48"},{"FGNo":"4","Actual":"38"},{"FGNo":"5","Actual":"41"},{"FGNo":"6","Actual":"16"}
```

I'm not sure how I can use the first array to arrange the second array like this

```
{"FGNo":"5","Actual":"41"},[{"FGNo":"3","Actual":"48"},{"FGNo":"4","Actual":"38"},,{"FGNo":"6","Actual":"16"}
```

I tried using nested for loops but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: what kind of data structure is the last one??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it is a mixture of copy/pasting the previous array thus probably json.

Comment: i used json array

Comment: *I have 2 queries* - get the result array by one query

Comment: i actually wanted to do that but i couldnt seem to make it work. i have a deadline so i had to improvise and i was hoping that i could make it work with this method

Answer (score 0):

This example uses [`usort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a custom value comparison function. Since your "arrays" are JSON objects we need to convert them to a PHP array using [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Then we need to create an array which is going to be used to sort the larger array.
*See the [code from hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885072/rearranging-php-arrays/42885585#comment72876565_42885585) below.*

```
$orderArray = json_decode('[{"FGNo":"5"},{"FGNo":"3"},{"FGNo":"4"},{"FGNo":"6"}]', true);
$arrayToSort = json_decode('[{"FGNo":"3","Actual":"48"},{"FGNo":"4","Actual":"38"},{"FGNo":"5","Actual":"41"},{"FGNo":"6","Actual":"16"}]', true);

$keys = array_flip(array_column($orderArray, 'FGNo'));

usort($arrayToSort, function($a, $b) use ($keys) {
    if ($keys[$a['FGNo']] == $keys[$b['FGNo']]) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $keys[$a['FGNo']] < $keys[$b['FGNo']] ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r(json_encode($arrayToSort));
// [{"FGNo":"5","Actual":"41"},{"FGNo":"3","Actual":"48"},{"FGNo":"4","Actual":"38"},{"FGNo":"6","Actual":"16"}]
```

*Don't forget to [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)    `$arrayToSort` after the `usort()` function!*

Comment: stop using `global` , use `use` instead, and use `array_column` instead of looping over `$alignmentArray` array

Comment: @AlexEspiritu I have made some changes to the code (as suggested by @hassan), it works the same but it is a little bit better.

Comment: @hassan thanks, added it to the answer (with appropriate name inclusion) :)